# GLX extension missing on display "localhost:10.0"

Tags: ssh, x11, nvidia, opengl

I have installed scilab 5.5.1 on rocks based cluster(with GPU card & nvidia driver installed), and i am able to successfully use scilab on the same .

Issue arises when i need to use scilab from a remote machine using a client say **putty / mobaxterm / ssh** .Is there a problem with the scilab's Xforwarding or i need to reinstall X11 ?.
The [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76005/x11-forwarding-an-opengl-application-from-a-machine-running-an-nvidia-card-to-a) was asked earlier , its answer was not much useful in my case.

```
The error is :
     [root@machine1] ./scilab
    Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display "localhost:10.0"
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'GiwsException::JniCallMethodException'
    what():  Exception when calling Java method : com/artenum/rosetta/ui/Console
     at org.scilab.modules.gui.ScilabConsoleBridge.createConsole(Unknown Source)....
```

I took a new CentOS machine with GPU card & nvidia driver , and running scilab gives silimar error:

```
[root@machine2] ./scilab
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
```

further ,

```
[root@machine2]# DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo|grep OpenGL
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Intel(R) HD Graphics
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (4.0.0 - Build 9.17.10.3223)
OpenGL extensions:
```

I have recreated my X configuration file via **X -configure** command & device section contains PCI BusID

```
[root@machine2]#strace ./scilab
execve("./scilab", ["./scilab"], [/* 33 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x2789000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f43b9856000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff28e920c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7fff28e920c0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff28e920c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff28e920c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/tls", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib64/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fff28e920c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=61440, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff28e920c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls", 0x7fff28e920c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff28e920c0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=76569, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 76569, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f43b9843000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY)  = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@\310\200\3162\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=138280, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x32ce800000, 2232320, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x32ce800000
mprotect(0x32ce81d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x32cea1d000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1d000) = 0x32cea1d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

access("./scilab-bin", X_OK)            = 0
stat("./scilab-bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=800049, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("./scilab-bin", R_OK)            = 0
stat("./scilab-bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=800049, ...}) = 0
stat("./scilab-bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=800049, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("./scilab-bin", X_OK)            = 0
stat("./scilab-bin", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=800049, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
getegid()                               = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getgid()                                = 0
access("./scilab-bin", R_OK)            = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
lseek(255, -1407, SEEK_CUR)             = 37474
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f43b98409d0) = 22118
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x43d220, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x32c4032a20}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x32c4032a20}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1, Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
```

(this is not full stack trace)

How can i fix the **error missing glx & nvglx** on **machine1 & machine 2**.
Any Hint/Help will be very useful.