# When running some X prog. remotely with ssh -X, it says "libGL error: failed to load driver: r600"

Tags: centos, ssh, x11, xorg

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

Kernel: 3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64

When I run xcrysden (http://www.xcrysden.org/) remotely through ssh -X, it crashes with error:

> "libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
>
> libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details."

But this happens only in ssh session. The program runs well locally.

The crash happens for only some programs but not all. I can run X programs such xterm, gnome-terminal, evince ... with ssh normally.  But when I run glxgears or glxinfo through ssh, it gives the same error.

```
$  LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose  glxinfo
name of display: localhost:12.0
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/r600_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/r600_dri.so
libGL error: failed to open drm device: No such file or directory
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should [read this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76017/25985) and see if you can forward `glxdemo` with your current method.