# Play crawl-tiles over SSH from Windows with PuTTY

Tags: ssh, x11, putty, opengl

I have a headless Raspberry Pi running PiBang (swapping to Raspbian soon since PiBang is no longer supported) which I'd like to play [Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup](http://crawl.develz.org/wordpress/) over ssh. When I try to run

```
crawl-tiles
```

it reads

```
Failed to initialize SDL: Unable to open a console terminal
```

I've tried using this command

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Nothing appears to happen. The device does not have a display connected, but my google queries usually pointed to that command.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

Here's some more info. I'm sshing into the RPi on a public computer using PuTTy. Googling **'x11 forwarding putty'** lead me to this page https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY which says to install something called Xming.

Now it says,

```
crawl-tiles
Failed to set video mode: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
```

which appears to be an entirely new problem in itself. Does anyone have any tips for sshing on a public computer without installing Xming or insight on the video mode error?

Comment: The complication here is probably openGL: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76005/x11-forwarding-an-opengl-application-from-a-machine-running-an-nvidia-card-to-a

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward your X connection:

```
ssh -X user@pi
```

You'll probably need `xauth` installed on the Pi as well.

Given that you're running via PuTTY on Windows, here are a couple of other things to try:

- plain `crawl` should work fine, it doesn't use graphics at all (it's the "console" version if you're downloading from the Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup web site);
- Xming supports GLX, so it should be possible to run `crawl-tiles` remotely using `ssh -X`; it's possible the error message you're seeing is because `crawl-tiles` is trying to change the screen resolution, so you can try `crawl-tiles -extra-opt-last tile_full_screen=false` to start it in a window.

You won't be able to run anything in graphics mode without an X server on the Windows end of things, either Xming or some other X server (OpenText Exceed...).

Comment: Is there a way to do this while already ssh'ed in?

Comment: Not that I know of, you'll probably need to open another `ssh` connection...

Comment: It doesn't appear to be that simple using PuTTy. I added more information in the question above. Thanks for your help.